# How to calculate time differences without copying

Tags: r, datetime, dispatch

I would like to compute the difference in seconds between two POSIXct objects without copying them. This shouldn't be a problem, because they are stored as `numeric` UNIX time, so a plain subtraction is all that is necessary. The issue is that the `-` operator is dispatched based on the classes of the objects, and `difftime` is called. The `difftime` function copies each input vector twice:

```
> a <- as.POSIXct(runif(1e6, 0, 1000), origin = '1970-01-01')
> b <- as.POSIXct(runif(1e6, 0, 1000), origin = '1970-01-01')
> a_trace <- tracemem(a)
> b_trace <- tracemem(b)
> z <- a - b
tracemem[0x000000004c082470 -> 0x000007fff54e0010]: difftime -.POSIXt 
tracemem[0x000007fff8c80010 -> 0x000007ffe9490010]: difftime -.POSIXt 
tracemem[0x000007ffe9490010 -> 0x000007ffe8530010]: structure .difftime difftime -.POSIXt 
tracemem[0x000007ffe8530010 -> 0x000007ffe7d80010]: structure .difftime difftime -.POSIXt
```

Another problem with this is that by default `difftime` may choose an output unit besides seconds. This is avoided by calling it explicitly with a units argument, but the four copies are still made:

```
> z <- difftime(a, b, units = 'secs')
tracemem[0x000000004c082470 -> 0x000007ffe70a0010]: difftime 
tracemem[0x000007fff8c80010 -> 0x000007ffe68f0010]: difftime 
tracemem[0x000007ffe68f0010 -> 0x000007ffde890010]: structure .difftime difftime 
tracemem[0x000007ffde890010 -> 0x000007ffde0e0010]: structure .difftime difftime
```

Also, the resulting object is of class `difftime`, instead of plain `numeric`. Using base R, an addtional copy of the result is necessary to eliminate the `difftime` class:

```
> z_trace <- tracemem(z)
> class(z) <- NULL
tracemem[0x000007ffb28e0010 -> 0x000007ffb2130010]:
```

Using `data.table::setattr` I have devised the following function:

```
fast_difftime <- function(a, b) {

  classA <- attr(a, 'class')
  classB <- attr(b, 'class')

  on.exit({
    data.table::setattr(a, 'class', classA)
    data.table::setattr(b, 'class', classB)
  })

  data.table::setattr(a, 'class', NULL)
  data.table::setattr(b, 'class', NULL)

  a - b

}
```

This avoids the copying, and is much faster:

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fast_difftime(a, b), as.numeric(difftime(a, b, units = "secs")))
Unit: milliseconds
                                       expr      min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval cld
                        fast_difftime(a, b) 1.728555  4.213836  5.97520  4.392592  6.365763 127.1690   100  a 
 as.numeric(difftime(a, b, units = "secs")) 6.643092 19.352806 24.54938 19.861066 23.298505 137.0776   100   b
```

However, I don't like the fact that I have to modify the attributes of the input vectors in-place, just to avoid method dispatch. Is there a better way?

Comment: `z <- c(unclass(a) - unclass(b))`?

Comment: `-` is not a normal S3 generic. You can't avoid method dispatch if you can't call an S3 method directly and you can't do that for the numerics method.

Comment: Your solution copies `a`, `b` and the resulting vector `unclass(a) - unclass(b)` each once.

Comment: By using `as.numeric` instead of `unclass`, you can drop the call to `c`. But we're still at one copy apiece for the input vectors.

Comment: I don't see a copy for `c`.

Comment: I was a little confused by this. `memtrace` doesn't show a copy, but `f <- function(a, b) {
  x <- unclass(a) - unclass(b);
  print(data.table::address(x));
  z <- c(x);
  print(data.table::address(z));
  z;
}` shows that the address of `x` does not match that of `z`. But `memtrace` is silent. Perhaps the address is misleading. And of course, if you run `z = c(w)` and modify `w`, `z` is not modified, so a copy must be made?

Comment: Umm, your code doesn't call `f`?

Comment: I meant if you call `f`.. anyway, this is out of scope for the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176341/discussion-between-mb7744-and-roland).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rcpp would be an option because you can ignore the class attribute:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction(
  'NumericVector mydiff(const NumericVector x, const NumericVector y) {
       return x - y;
   }
  ')


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fast_difftime(a, b), mydiff(a, b))
#Unit: milliseconds
#                expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
# fast_difftime(a, b) 2.248841 2.291861 3.489386 2.326559 2.379951 46.69430   100   a
#        mydiff(a, b) 2.165105 2.209661 3.089114 2.229380 2.272144 10.96047   100   a
```

Comment: Ah, duh. That's much more straightforward than `setattr` shenanigans. I realize now I shouldn't have intertwined two questions: (1) how to subtract dates without copy, and (2) how to control dispatch with primitives, if possible). But this is a great answer to (1). I'll edit the question to focus just on (1).